# Anyone know what I am doing wrong to execute this java code?

Tags: java

I am just trying to execute some Java code and print them out to the console, however, when I try to run it, it gives an error and says illegal start to expression. Does anyone know what is going on here?

```
    package com.craneai;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public static void int F(int N) {
            int X, Y, Z, I;

            int X = 2;
            if(N <= 0) {
                X = 3;
            } else {
                Y = 1;
                Z = 1;
                for (int I = 3; I <=N; I++) {
                    X = Y + Z;
                    Z = Y;
                    Y = X;
                }
            }
            return X;
        }


        System.out.println(F(6));
        System.out.println(F(0));
        System.out.println(F(1));

    }



}
```

Comment: Java does not have nested methods.  Move method `F()` out of `main()`.  Also, although not technically required, do follow standard Java naming conventions: methods are named in camel case with an initial *lowercase* letter.

Comment: and you have declared variable twice like I and X

Comment: but why are doing this to yourself? just put the code in an `IDE`

Comment: Ok guys, I moved the method out of main, and I updated the post to show what I have. It is now saying identifier expected.

Comment: There are some few things to fix before you try to run your code again, check below the answer I provided, I've listed some little things that you missed and some more. @kennyman335

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(F(6));
        System.out.println(F(0));
        System.out.println(F(1));

    }

    public static int F(int N) {
        int X, Y, Z, I;

        X = 2;
        if(N <= 0) {
            X = 3;
        } else {
            Y = 1;
            Z = 1;
            for (int i = 3; i <=N; i++) {
                X = Y + Z;
                Z = Y;
                Y = X;
            }
        }
        return X;
    }
```

A few things to consider:

1st. You're declaring a void return and then a int, the function must have only 1 return type.

```
public static void int F(int N)
```

2nd. The method should be outside the `main` method

3rd. You declared `X` twice in the code, the second time you call it, you don't have to declare the type, the compiler will try to process it as a new variable with a name that is already in use.

4th. In your `for` method, you declared `X`, once again, Java is case sensitive, so `X` and `x` are different in the compiler.

5th. You've also declared `I` twice, you don't need to provide a temporary variable before calling the `for` method, since you can do it inside the `for` loop;

Looks like you're starting to learn Java, a few tips from who works with it since the Java 5..

- Don't declare your variables with a single letter;
- Don't declare your functions/methods with a single letter;
- Don't declare your variables in UPPER CASE, always low case and camelCase;

Even as an example you should make your code cleaner, improve the readability for others, other people will be happier in the future if you do this (this include yourself).

Answer (score 0):

First: you're declaring a method inside another method - see that the `F` method is inside the `main` method. Java does not support nested methods.

Second: you're declaring `X` and `I` twice.

Third: You wrote two return types to your method: `void` and `int`.

This will work:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(F(6));
        System.out.println(F(0));
        System.out.println(F(1));
    }

    public static int F(int N) {
        int X, Y, Z, I;

        X = 2;
        if (N <= 0) {
            X = 3;
        } else {
            Y = 1;
            Z = 1;
            for (I = 3; I <= N; I++) {
                X = Y + Z;
                Z = Y;
                Y = X;
            }
        }
        return X;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three main errors:

1. Nested method: `F` method inside `main`
2. Method F return `int` and `void`
3. You declared X and I twice.

Here is your class fixed:

```
public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(F(6));
            System.out.println(F(0));
            System.out.println(F(1));
    
        }
    
        public static int F(int N) {
            int X = 2, Y, Z;
    
            if (N <= 0) {
                X = 3;
            } else {
                Y = 1;
                Z = 1;
                for (int I = 3; I <= N; I++) {
                    X = Y + Z;
                    Z = Y;
                    Y = X;
                }
            }
            return X;
        }
    }
```

Output is going to be this:

```
8
3
2
```

Comment: You're trying to reassign the value of `I` inside the `for` loop or just forgot to change to lower case `i`?

Comment: Am i doing what? Where do you see the reassignent of I inside the loop? I removed the declaration of variable I which was previously declared along with the other variables, then only declaring and initializing I with the for (that's the way a for works). Plus, I didn't forget the lower case: Java is case sensitive, I am just using all upper case for not to change too much the code already written.

Comment: Ohh, right sorry, I posted a comment on the wrong answer hehe.

Comment: no worries :) if u think it's ok, just vote up.